# Setting Knitr options

Tags: knitr

The following code chunk doesn't work I get an error message and it disrupts the compilation of my document. Not sure if anyone has any ideas? Very M WE below. As @Speravir pointed out, not sure it adds much to enlighten. This is really about getting efficient code together..

The error message is `Error object options_chunk not found`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Testing knitr


<<set-options>>=
options_chunk$set(cache=TRUE,cache.path='Data/Cache/',warning=FALSE,error=FALSE,message=FALSE)
@
 Something in the middle to prove its working   
<<somechunk,results='asis'>>=
 a=1
 b=2
 print(a+b)
@
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is `opts_chunk` instead of `options_chunk`. See http://yihui.name/knitr/options